# Should I use repeated measures ANOVa for the crossover design?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have the following crossover design:
[image]

So I measure a certain parameter before intervention, and after. Should I use repeated-measures ANOVA to test the hypothesis that H0: there is no difference between Treatment A and B or is there more appropriate test to do?

Comment: One approach is to use the baseline (pre-test) measurements as covariate and fit a mixed model with random subject effect and fixed effect for treatment (A or B), period (1 or 2) and sequence (AB or BA). See Ch. 3 of "Cross-over Trials in Clinical Research" by S. Senn.